# Uncaught ReferenceError ajuda?

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tendo esse seguinte erro:

Uncaught ReferenceError: szClose is not defined

```
at jquery.colorbox.js?x=30:45
at jquery.colorbox.js?x=30:1026
```

onde está o problema?

```js
(function ($, document, window) {
 var
 // Default settings object.
 // See http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox for details.
 defaults = {
  transition: "none",
  speed: 300,
  fadeOut: 300,
  width: false,
  initialWidth: "400",
  innerWidth: false,
  maxWidth: false,
  height: false,
  initialHeight: "150",
  innerHeight: false,
  maxHeight: false,
  scalePhotos: true,
  scrolling: false,
  inline: false,
  html: false,
  iframe: false,
  fastIframe: true,
  photo: false,
  href: false,
  title: true,
  rel: false,
  opacity: 0.8,
  preloading: false,
  className: false,

  // alternate image paths for high-res displays
  retinaImage: false,
  retinaUrl: false,
  retinaSuffix: '@2x.$1',

  // internationalization
  current: "image {current} of {total}",
  previous: "previous",
  next: "next",
  close: szClose,
  xhrError: "This content failed to load.",
  imgError: "This image failed to load.",
```

Comment: O código está incompleto [tente colocar um exemplo mínimo verificável que reproduza o problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Está a usar um plugin de jquery para cor ? Colocou a tag `php` porque tem algum código de `php` associado a este que cause o problema? Aproveite e tente [detalhar ao máximo o seu problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: não entendi o code ta ai a parte que esta dando erro

Comment: Pois mas a parte que está a dar o erro não é a unica que contribui para o erro. Já para não falar que mesmo o trecho de código que colocou não está completo pois faltaria no minimo os fechos dos `(` e `{` abertos. Aconselho no entanto a colocar a utilização desse `defauts` e até o html associado

Answer (score 0):

Lendo a documentação do plugin [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) nota-se na sessão `Settings` ( Configurações ) que a opção `close` recebe valor tipo `Texto` ou `HTML`, o erro está ocorrendo porque `szClose` não existe.

Você pode resolver de dois jeitos.

- Criar uma variável antes da linha `var defaults`

  ```
  var szClose = "Fechar";
  ```
- Alterar o valor da opção `close`

  ```
  close: "Fechar"
  ```

Obs: Só respondi, porque o erro está claro ainda que o código não esteja completo.